# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, arguments

newbie here practicing laravel, im making an inventory for movies using laravel 5.6.. where I can do basic CRUD functionalities.

In here, Im sorting movies by genre. however I came up with this error Invalid argument supplied for foreach();

**here is my Route: web.php**

Route::resource('movies', 'MoviesController');

Route::get('movies/year/{movie}', 'MoviesController@released');

Route::get('movies/genre/{genre}', 'MoviesController@getgenre');

**here is my controller: MoviesController.php**

```
public function getgenre($genre){
    $movies = Movie::where('genre', $genre)->whereIn('status', [1])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();
    return view('genre', compact('movies'));
}
```

**here is my view: genre.blade.php**

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @if($movies->count() < 1)
            <h1 style="text-align: center">No Movie Found</h1>
        @else
            @foreach($movies as $movie)
                <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            {{ ucwords($movie->title) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            {{ ucfirst($movie->genre) }} | {{$movie->released}} | 

                            @if($movie->seen == 1)
                                Seen: Yes
                            @else
                                Seen: No
                            @endif

                            <div style="margin-top: 5px">
                                {{ Form::open(['route' => ['movies.edit', $movie->id], 'class' => 'formupdate', 'method' => 'GET']) }}
                                    {{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary col-md-2']) }}
                                {{ Form::close() }}
                            </div>

                            <div style="margin-top: 5px">
                                {{ Form::open(['route' => ['movies.destroy', $movie->id], 'class' => 'formdelete', 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}

                                    {{ Form::hidden('hidden', 'hidden') }}
                                    {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger col-md-2']) }}
                                {{ Form::close() }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach

        <div class="pagination" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
            {{ $movie->links() }}
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

@stop

I tested it dd(): and it has results:

[tried testing it using dd()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRfpV.png)

here is the error:
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2xw.png)

thanks,

Comment: Please add code not image or links of code

Comment: If you're a newbie you would better start with CI and work your way to laravel.

Comment: @hungrykoala ... I was told that laravel is good for beginners.. however I will also consider CI.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two issues:
1- Update this  whereIn expects array and you use pagination in view and you do not return the data as pagination

```
      $movies = Movie::where('genre', $genre)->whereIn('status', [1])>orderBy('title', 'asc')->paginate(10);
```

2- in the view you written $movie->links(); update it to

```
        $movies->links();
```

Comment: your suggestion works fine. thank you
.. i also tried using a where clause having two parameters (genre and status) instead of using wherein for status alone. But why does placing a [ ] solves the issue?

Comment: because whereIn expects array so you must but the conditions in array

Answer (score 0):

Update this line, `whereIn` expects array

```
$movies = Movie::where('genre', $genre)->whereIn('status', [1])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();
```